# Como somar elementos de duas Streams em java?

Tags: java, programação-funcional

Olá, gostaria de fazer uma função que soma os elementos de duas Streams e retorna uma Stream com os resultados, de maneira "funcional" sem usar bibliotecas de terceiros. Por exemplo:

```
BiFunction<Stream,Stream,Stream> mySoma = (s1,s2) -> ?????? ;
```

Conheço pouco da linguagem e tentei procurar algo como um `zipWith` ou em ultimo caso algo para iterar, como um `get()`, mas não encontrei nada que funcionasse. Existe algo que faça isso?

(PS: Posso mudar para IntStream se isso ajudar de alguma coisa).

Comment: Somar o total de todos os elementos das duas streams, ou somar elemento a elemento como se fosse uma nova stream com a soma de cada par ?

Comment: Gostaria de fazer a soma de cada par de elementos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não existe uma função semelhante a `zipWith` na API de *Streams* do Java. Ela chegou a ser implementada em uma *build* do Java 8 mas foi retirada porque, na visão dos responsáveis pela linguagem, tal funcionalidade seria melhor provida por bibliotecas, ou mesmo cada desenvolvedor poderia implementar sua própria versão que atendesse suas necessidades.

Entre os problemas citados por ele estão:

- é um idioma de outras linguagens que não se adapta bem ao Java por causa da inexistência de tuplas e outros tipos;
- na versão atual do Java, não é possível criar uma versão que aceite tipos primitivos, o que pode gerar problemas de performance devido ao *boxing* e *unboxing* das variáveis, além da necessidade da criação de novos *SAM types*;
- difícil de paralelizar;
- múltiplas formas de lidar com *Streams* de tamanhos distintos. Qual deveria ser escolhido?

Você pode acompanhar toda a discussão sobre isso [aqui](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2013-June/010071.html).

Sendo assim, você terá que implementar uma solução própria, ou utilizar alguma biblioteca que possua tal funcionalidade, como [guava](https://github.com/google/guava).

Como referência, a guava implementa esse método [dessa forma](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Streams.java#L214):

```
/**
 * Returns a stream in which each element is the result of passing the corresponding elementY of
 * each of {@code streamA} and {@code streamB} to {@code function}.
 *
 * <p>For example:
 *
 * <pre>{@code
 * Streams.zip(
 *   Stream.of("foo1", "foo2", "foo3"),
 *   Stream.of("bar1", "bar2"),
 *   (arg1, arg2) -> arg1 + ":" + arg2)
 * }</pre>
 *
 * <p>will return {@code Stream.of("foo1:bar1", "foo2:bar2")}.
 *
 * <p>The resulting stream will only be as long as the shorter of the two input streams; if one
 * stream is longer, its extra elements will be ignored.
 *
 * <p>Note that if you are calling {@link Stream#forEach} on the resulting stream, you might want
 * to consider using {@link #forEachPair} instead of this method.
 *
 * <p><b>Performance note:</b> The resulting stream is not <a
 * href="http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/StreamParallelGuidance.html">efficiently splittable</a>.
 * This may harm parallel performance.
 */
 public static <A, B, R> Stream<R> zip(
      Stream<A> streamA, Stream<B> streamB, BiFunction<? super A, ? super B, R> function) {
    checkNotNull(streamA);
    checkNotNull(streamB);
    checkNotNull(function);
    boolean isParallel = streamA.isParallel() || streamB.isParallel(); // same as Stream.concat
    Spliterator<A> splitrA = streamA.spliterator();
    Spliterator<B> splitrB = streamB.spliterator();
    int characteristics =
        splitrA.characteristics()
            & splitrB.characteristics()
            & (Spliterator.SIZED | Spliterator.ORDERED);
    Iterator<A> itrA = Spliterators.iterator(splitrA);
    Iterator<B> itrB = Spliterators.iterator(splitrB);
    return StreamSupport.stream(
            new AbstractSpliterator<R>(
                Math.min(splitrA.estimateSize(), splitrB.estimateSize()), characteristics) {
              @Override
              public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super R> action) {
                if (itrA.hasNext() && itrB.hasNext()) {
                  action.accept(function.apply(itrA.next(), itrB.next()));
                  return true;
                }
                return false;
              }
            },
            isParallel)
        .onClose(streamA::close)
        .onClose(streamB::close);
}
```

Observação: o método `checkNotNull` também é parte do guava. Caso você queira utilizar tal implementação sem utilizar a biblioteca, você pode substituí-lo pelo método `Objects.requireNonNull`.